# Publication error with ScholarOne?

Tags: publications, online-publication

I am trying to publish a publication in the web site of a journal, and when I put my .tex file (also .png files) the website gives an error and says "File will not display in proof". I think it is treated by ScholarOne.

Do you have any solution for that or may I have to contact ScholarOne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with source files. For the `.tex` file that is OK: in fact, the `.tex` file should not appear in the proof. For the pictures, it probably means that ScholarOne doesn't process `.png` files: convert them to a supported file format, e.g. `.pdf` or `.tiff`.

In my experience, the above is usually enough to make the proof work, and if it's OK, submit, even if you still get that message for the `.tex` file.

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean by "the .tex file should not appear in the proof. " ?

Comment: @BriganosBriganos The proof is what the reviewers will receive to read; typically, the compiled manuscript with added line numbers: the listing of the `.tex` file is not shown, so it doesn't appear in the proof.

Comment: i changed .png to Pdf and it it gives again this error (Unable to find any suitable files to generate the proof) !! do you have any idea ? thanks

Comment: @BriganosBriganos But have you uploaded also _your_ compiled pdf?

Comment: yes i compiled my Latex files, and put them together in a .zip file and uploaded!

Comment: @BriganosBriganos Upload the compiled pdf separately and ad type of file select the option "Complete manuscript for review".

Comment: NICE!!  it works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Contact someone at the journal. They decide what system to use for processing your article, so they should help you navigate that system.